# How to make `write()` system call on Linux immediately effective?

Tags: linux, system-calls, fwrite

I am writing a REPL(read-execute-print-loop) for C.  I try to maintain a header file so that I can define new functions based on the previous functions.  Whenever I define a new function, I get a new temporary file like this:

```
#include "/tmp/header.h"

int foo() {
    return func() * func();
}
```

And the `/tmp/header.h` is like:

```
int func();
int foo();
```

where `func()` is a previously defined function.

So I need to call `write()` on `header_fileno` again and again.  What I am concerned is---is it possible that after I called `write(header_fileno, buf, wrsize)`, the contents of `buf` is **stored in some kernel buffer** instead of **being written into the actual file**?  Because if that happens, I cannot count on the header to give up-to-date declarations.  I have the same concern when it comes to the source file.  And if that happens, is there a way to make it immediately effective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may safely assume that any process, including the current one, which makes a `read()` call after you've called `write()` will see the updated file, even if the file is still in a kernel buffer and not fully written to disk. POSIX [mandates](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) this behavior:

> If a read() of file data can be proven (by any means) to occur after a write() of the data, it must reflect that write(), even if the calls are made by different processes.

Having said that, this doesn't apply if you use the stdio functions, which may buffer data before writing. It also doesn't guarantee that your data won't be lost or corrupted if your system crashes; if you need that guarantee, you must use `fsync()` or open the file with `O_SYNC`.

Comment: "... you must use fsync()" or open the file with flag O_SYNC

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write), there is no guarantee that `write` will commit your data to disk. Use `fsync` (or close the file) to flush the written data to the disk. (`lseek` might also be useful, if you want to use just one file descriptor.)

However, if you are going to be modifying the contents of the files frequently, as you might expect in a REPL, you might want to store them in memory instead, so you can manipulate them more easily.

Similarly, rather than storing live REPL code as text, you might want to store its information in another form, so you can access and change it more easily.

Comment: OP's concern is that "the header [gives] up-to-date declarations". No need to fsync the file for that, see bk2204's answer. And if you don't fsync at each write, then no need to store anything in memory, kernel cache will play that role and I/O will be fast.